# AngularJs newItem.push() onto select options

Tags: angularjs

Fairly new to AngularJS and first time posting here.  On a data entry page, I display a select list where the options in the list come from an array.  The array can have items added which need to be reflected in the select list.  I can see the items are being added to the array but the options list is not updating without reloading the entire page.

How does one update or refresh the select options list after it has been initialized?

```
<select ng-model="VendorsController.selectedVendor.Items.selectedItem.locno" 
    style="width:300px;" 
    size="1" 
    ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in VendorsController.selectedVendor.Locations" 
    required >
</select>
```

The new item is saved on the server with a callback and the promiss has the following statement to push the new (Location) item onto the array.

```
_this.selectedVendor.Locations.push(_this.selectedVendor.Locations.selectedLoc);
```

The array reflects the new item was pushed correctly but the options list does not show it.  Any suggestions?

Here is some additional code about where I call on the push().

```
this.SaveLocation = function(){
    $http.post('cfm/callback4.cfmx', _this.selectedVendor.Locations.selectedLoc ).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // if new location pk now reflects valid data
             _this.selectedVendor.Locations.selectedLoc = data;
             //console.log(data);
            //console.log(status);
            //console.log(config);

             // add location to list
            if (_this.selectedVendor.Locations.addNew) {
                _this.selectedVendor.Locations.selectedLoc.value = data.locno

                // this push is not showing up on the locations options
_this.selectedVendor.Locations.push(_this.selectedVendor.Locations.selectedLoc);

            }
            // must reset after promiss is returned
            _this.selectedVendor.Locations.originalLoc = undefined;
            _this.selectedVendor.Locations.selectedLoc = undefined; // null;
            _this.selectedVendor.Locations.addNew = false ;

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
            console.log(data)
            console.log(status)
            console.log(config)

        });
}; // end SaveLocation
```

And my form button that calls the above function.

```
<button ng-show="VendorsController.selectedVendor.Locations.selectedLoc" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="VendorsController.SaveLocation()">Save</button>
```

Here is how I create the controller... A friend that understands more about AngularJS suggested I use the _this when I'm calling on properties within functions of the controller... something to do with scope or at least that is the way I understood it.

```
app.controller('VendorsController', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'state','$timeout','$upload', function ($scope, $window, $http, $routeParams, $location, state, $timeout,$upload) {

var _this = this; // the controller
this.name = "VendorsController";
this.params = $routeParams;
```

Comment: Can you give more of the code around where you're pushing it onto the list? Is this outside of "angular world" where you need to call `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: I have a button with ng-click that points to a function SaveEdit().  This function then does a callback to the server to save the change that occurred.  After returning from the server I try to push().  I messed around with $apply but ran into some rootscope message, I guessed because I had no idea what I was doing...:-(  Also not sure yet how to post more code to my original posting...

Comment: What was the $rootScope message? It sounds like an apply issue. Or an inheritance issue where you are not actually logging out the same bound data variable. Do you have the option to edit posts? Edit link is just under the angularjs tag. It would be great if you could simulate the issue with a jsFiddle or something similar.

Comment: Ah, I see you edited the post. My mistake.

Comment: What is `_this` in that controller code? I've never seen anyone bind to a controller (i.e. `ng-model="VendorsController.selectedVendor.Items.selectedItem.locno"`). My best guess at this point (depending on how you initialized the controller) is that you need to be putting `selectedVendor` on `$scope` instead and binding to that (which is the main way people handle binding in angular). If this turns out to be the issue, I'll write up something fuller with an example.

Comment: I added code to show what _this is but I don't know how to explain it.